# SQL correlated columns filter and sort

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, faceted-search

I have a table with many columns with different types, which I am using to filter and sort results (it is similar to faceted search with sorting).

Let's consider 2 columns: `A` and `B`. For each column an index is created.

We want to query `A=value ORDER BY B LIMIT 10`.

If the planner will use `A` index then it must scan all rows with `A=value` and sort them by `B`.

If the planner will use `B`  index then it scan all rows until finds 10 rows with `A=value`.

We have 2500000 rows in total, 50000 rows with `A=value`, so there is one `A=value` per 50 rows, so it thinks to scan only 50*10=500 rows to find 10 `A=value` rows. However, it is wrong, because there is correlation between both fields and `A=value` rows are not evenly distributed, but they are at the end of `B` index, so it actually need to scan more than 2000000 rows.

If we disable `B` index then it is fine. However, we want `B` index for other queries.

How to solve the issue?

Creating `(A,B ASC)` index is not a good solution. Because there would be to many indexes and `A` might be of array type which doesn't support such index.

Comment: Have you tried adding extended statistics to tell the planner about the dependency?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html#PLANNER-STATS-EXTENDED

Comment: @Jeremy Yes, I tried adding statistics over `(A,B)`, but it does not change anything. Extended statistics does not cover such case.

Comment: @Jeremy  There is currently no extended statistics type which deals with this.

Answer (score 1):

There are no great general solutions for this. You can force it to not use the index on B for ordering on a case by case basis in SQL by adding some dummy operation to it, like:

```
ORDER BY B+0 LIMIT 10
```

or

```
ORDER BY B||'' LIMIT 10
```

There is always the possibility that some future version of PostgreSQL could "see through" these dummy operations and use that index anyway.

If the index on B is only desired to support equality comparisons, then you can make it a HASH index or a GIN index (via the btree_gin extension), which can't be used for ordering but can still be used for equality.

Comment: Thank you. I need also just ordering without filtering `ORDER BY B LIMIT 10` so btree index on B is needed.